# Group JavaScript array items by comparing items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var oArr = [
  { id: "d1", x: 2, y: 2 },
  { id: "d1", x: 3, y: 3 },
  { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 3 },
  { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 7 },
  { id: "d1", x: 3, y: 6 },

];
```

I want to subtract all the `y` properties to each other and test if it is smaller then the given threshold value.

And finally group items in nested-arrays...

```
var threshold =2;
```

So my expected output is:

```
var result= [
 [ { id: "d1", x: 2, y: 2 },{ id: "d1", x: 3, y: 3 }, { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 3 }],
  [ { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 7 }, { id: "d1", x: 3, y: 6 }]

];
```

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by: i want to subtract all items' "y" properties to each other and test if it is smaller then the given threshold value

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I removed the second part as you mentioned you already know it and it will consdered as "Too Broad". Please avoid asking multiple questions in one question

Comment: As for the first part, your question is still unclear. *"I want to subtract all items' "y" properties to each other"* What do you mean by this?

Comment: subtract all items y to each other: you want to list all possible pairs and then subtract ? subtraction is not commutative, we need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if the delta is not greater then the given `threshold`.

This solution requires a sorted array.

```js
var array = [{ id: "d1", x: 2, y: 2 }, { id: "d1", x: 3, y: 3 }, { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 3 }, { id: "d1", x: 5, y: 7 }, { id: "d1", x: 3, y: 6 }],
    threshold = 2,
    result = array
        .sort(({ y: a }, { y: b }) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
            if (!i || o.y - a[i - 1].y > threshold) {
                r.push([]);
            }
            r[r.length - 1].push(o);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and understanding me:).it works great.can u clearify reduce arguments

Comment: `r` is the accumulator and later the final result, `o` is each object of the array, `i` is the actual index of the item, `a` is the reference to the array, which is used for iterating. so the first check is checking the index first and if falsy (then it's index 0) or if the delta is greater than the threshold, then a new array is pushed to the result set, indicating a new group.

Comment: Ok i got it. thanks again for clearifying and functional solution Nina